# Rufus Scheduler - Catch exception and perform conditional statement

Tags: ruby, exception, dropbox, conditional-statements, rufus-scheduler

I have the a rufus scheduler which executes a request to Dropbox to check if the access key and secret are authorised every 10 minutes.

If it is unauthorised, the following exception is reported:

```
DropboxAuthError in GalleryController#index

#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized:0x7ef04c8>
```

The code I have in my scheduler to detect this is from the rufus-scheduler documentation:

```
def scheduler.on_exception(job, exception)
  puts "job #{job.job_id} caught exception '#{exception}'"
end
```

Because I am only wanting to catch that exception above, I want to be able to perform a conditional statement which compares the exception with a value, something like:

```
 def scheduler.on_exception(job, exception)
  if exception == "DropboxAuthError"
    puts "job #{job.job_id} caught exception '#{exception}'"
  end
 end
```

But because the exception is an object, I cannot do that comparison.

Has anyone got any idea's how I can do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin a cat

```
if exception.message.match(/DropboxAuthError/)
  # ...
end

if exception.is_a?(Net::HTTPUnauthorized)
  # ...
end
```

Don't be afraid of your Ruby objects.

Note that you could avoid the global error handling you've picked from rufus-scheduler documentation and do something like:

```
scheduler.every '10m' do
  begin
    # do the API call...
  rescue Net::HTTPUnauthorized => ne
    puts "not authorized"
  rescue => e
    puts "something wrong happened " + e.inspect
  end  
end
```

Where rescue does the type checking for you.

Cheers.